# Is it possible to interact with my personal Facebook wall and feed through the API anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been playing with the Graph API and can successfully interact with pages with no problem. However, I cannot find anything on the web, here on SO, or in the Facebook documents that says if you can, and then how to, interact with your personal profile wall and/or feed.

I'd just like to make my own code to post things to Facebook - preferably using Python - and retrieve what my friends are posting.

Is any of this still possible?

EDIT: this question was closed by admins but the explanation does not make sense. This question can be and was answered with facts, and I did over 3 days of research and testing before posting. SO, please provide a way to appeal or contact someone if you're going to shut down questions unjustly, please!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting to a user wall is not possible with the API anymore, the permission `publish_actions` got removed a while ago. Only posting to Pages is possible nowadays.

Also, access to data of friends who did not authorize your App is not possible, for data privacy reasons.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if the same goes for Groups?

Comment: see docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#posting-on-a-group